# REST-Requests not executed in newman due to not correct usage of ssl-certificates

Tags: ssl, newman

Im currently using Newman for automatically testing my Rest-API calls.

The problem is i can run all my tests in Postman without any problems, using the certificates (.pem and pkcs8) for ssl authorization within Postman is also not a problem. But when i try to load a Collection into Newman on the command-line, i cannot run the tests because the certificates - which are recommended correctly in Postman are not recommended corretly in Newman.

if i run:

`newman run postman_collection.json --ssl-client-cert cert.pfx --ssl-client-passphrase passphrase`

Then no request is executed. if I instead use:

`newman run postman_collection.json --ssl-client-cert cert.crt --ssl-client-key key.pkcs8 client-passphrase passphrase`

so Using the key and authorization certificate both separately (cert.crt, key.pkcs8) and not together in a .pfx file, then it executes requests but says that it "Couldnt validate first certificate", so every request returns an error.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround this using parameter --insecure  instead parameters "--ssl-client-cert cert.crt --ssl-client-key key.pkcs8 client-passphrase passphrase"